# Question about 3d collision of 2 particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, inertial-frames

I'm wondering about how to calculate the resultant velocity vectors of an elastic collision of two particles of same mass, in 3d. I've seen a post on the subject in which you answered, but I didn't quite get it...
I know you have to calculate the velocity and direction of the normal vector but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine resultant velocity of an elastic particle-particle collision in 3d space](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79047/). Please see [my answer on that page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/184955/12029)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: (I had assumed the asker had too much prior knowledge)

Okay, so in any collision momentum is conserved. This means that
$$m_1\vec{v}_1+m_2 \vec{v}_2=m_1 \vec{v}_1'+m_2\vec{v}_2'$$
Where $\vec{v}_i$ is the initial velocity of particle i and $\vec{v}_i'$ is the final velocity of particle i.

Furthermore, by definition, for an elastic collision the kinetic energy is conserved, so 
$$\frac{1}{2}m_1 v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2 v_2^2 = \frac{1}{2}m_1 v_1'^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2 v_2'^2 $$

Using these two equations, you can find the final velocities given the initial velocities.